# How to prevent/stop click propagation in vuejs

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a recursive list (tree) and each element has a `@click="sayHello(el.id)"`. Now the problem is, since it is a nested list like:

```
list-element-0-01
├──list-el-1-01
│   └──list-el-2-01
└──list-el-1-02
    └──list-el-2-02
```

If I click the element: `list-el-2-01` then I get the output of

```
 > "list-el-2-01"
 > "list-el-1-01"
 > "list-el-0-01"
```

In exact that order. I mean I get it, looking at the html:

```
<ul>
  <li @click="sayHello('list-el-0-01')"> one-one

    <ul>
      <li @click="sayHello('list-el-1-01')"> two-one
        <ul>
          <li @click="sayHello('list-el-2-01')"> three-one </li> // I click this
        </ul>
      </li>

      <li @click="sayHello('list-el-1-02')"> two-two
        <ul>
          <li @click="sayHello('list-el-2-02')"> three-two </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </li>
</ul>
```

It makes sense that I am also clicking all the wrapping elements, somehow. My question - is there a way to only have the **exact** element fire it's click event?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can stop propogation using the `.stop` event modifier  as:

```
@click.stop="sayHello"
```

Now the event won't be propagated to the parent

More on the list of event modifiers: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers

Comment: Works with vue js 2.96

Comment: How to do the opposite? Stop click from going to child.

Comment: @MarsAndBack try using `.self` in the parent